# Cannot merge two sorted arrays in JavaScript when second array has 0

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to write a function that would merge two sorted array a and b. However, when array b has a 0, it would only show array a as the output:

```
function mergeSortedArrays(a,b) {
  var merged = [],
  aElm = a[0],
  bElm = b[0],
  i = 1, //index for array a
  j = 1; //index for array b

  if (a.length == 0) {
    return b;
  }
  if (b.length == 0) {
    return a;
  }

  while (aElm || bElm) {
    if ((aElm && !bElm) || aElm < bElm) { //problem is that it thinks that 0 == !bElm
      merged.push(aElm);
      aElm = a[i++];
    } else {
      merged.push(bElm);
      bElm = b[j++];
    }
  }
  return merged;
}
mergeSortedArrays([2,5,6,9], [0,1,2,3,29]) //outputs [2,5,6,9]
```

I understand the problem is because 0 is falsey so under the condition `if(aElm && !bElm)`, it'll just constantly push aElm into `merged`. What would be a better way of writing the conditional so that it recognizes the 0 as a integer rather than not existing?

Comment: `0` is a falsey value in JS. Try checking `value === undefined`

Comment: `Number(aElm)` to determine a Number-Type?

Comment: @Rajesh Thank you so much for the suggestion. What I tried doing was value === false, but it didn't work. I forgot that false !=== undefined.

Comment: isn't simplert to simply concat the arrays and then sort the result? [2,5,6,9].concat([0,1,2,3,29]).sort()

Comment: @RobertoBisello Yes, I know i can just .concat and then use sort, but I'm trying to figure out how to do it without using built in methods

Comment: @RobertoBisello Because sort has a worse than linear complexity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What would be a better way of writing the conditional so that it recognizes the 0 as a integer rather than not existing?

A better way of writing the condition would be to not test for the existence of the array element, but rather check the index.

```
function mergeSortedArrays(a,b) {
  var merged = [],
      i = 0, //index for array a
      j = 0; //index for array b

  while (i < a.length || j < b.length) {
    if (j == b.length || a[i] < b[j]) {
      merged.push(a[i++]);
    } else {
      merged.push(b[j++]);
    }
  }
  return merged;
}
```

Comment: This is definitely better than the way I wrote it, as it simplifies the code and gets rid of the need to compare to undefined. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could explicit check for `undefined` values.

```js
function mergeSortedArrays(a, b) {
    var merged = [],
        aElm = a[0],
        bElm = b[0],
        i = 1, //index for array a
        j = 1; //index for array b

    if (a.length == 0) {
        return b;
    }
    if (b.length == 0) {
        return a;
    }

    while (aElm !== undefined || bElm !== undefined) {
        if ((aElm !== undefined && bElm === undefined) || aElm < bElm) {
            merged.push(aElm);
            aElm = a[i++];
        } else {
            merged.push(bElm);
            bElm = b[j++];
        }
    }
    return merged;
}

console.log(mergeSortedArrays([2, 5, 6, 9], [0, 1, 2, 3, 29]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, writing out the conditions explicitly would definitely ensure no mistakes

Answer (score 0):

Try for `> -1` as `(aElm >-1) && !(bElm>-1)` if there is no negative number

```js
function mergeSortedArrays(a,b) {
  var merged = [],
  aElm = a[0],
  bElm = b[0],
  i = 1, //index for array a
  j = 1; //index for array b

  if (a.length == 0) {
    return b;
  }
  if (b.length == 0) {
    return a;
  }

  while ((aElm >-1) || (bElm>-1)) {
    if (((aElm >-1) && !(bElm>-1)) || aElm < bElm) { //problem is that it thinks that 0 == !bElm
      merged.push(aElm);
      aElm = a[i++];
    } else {
      merged.push(bElm);
      bElm = b[j++];
    }
  }
  return merged;
}
var result = mergeSortedArrays([2,5,6,9], [0,1,2,3,29]) //outputs [2,5,6,9]
console.log(result);
```

**Also what about this solution**

```js
var a = [2,5,6,9];
var b = [0,1,2,3,29];

a = a.concat(b);
a.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm looking to have it sort negative elements as well. As for the second solution, I did have that in mind, but I'm looking to figure it out without using built in methods such as .concat and .sort